2008 civic ex where do wires from connector on top of alternator run to
There is a connector on the top of the alternator with 3 wires ((two black, one red) that appear to run down to the ac compressor. Does one of these supply power to the ac clutch?
I want to verify functionality of clutch by applying power to it.

I doubt any alternator controls ac clutch power when its the hvac control panel inside the vehicle that commands when ac is needed. Wiring you see may be simply wire bundling. To power the compressor, simply disconnect the single or dual connector to the compressor and hot wire the compressor to the battery directly without the engine running. A single wire means 12v from battery to this wire; ground is the  clutch coil grounded to the compressor frame to engine block ground. Two wires; one is for 12v, the other is a separate ground and a continuity test is needed to find the ground wire.. Power applied should result in a metallic click as the clutch plate slaps into the idler pulley face.

The connector uses the alternator for support for the connector. It has no electrical connection to the alternator. The question is:  Is this a power feed for the compressor clutch which is difficult to see because of location.

In my limited experience as a diyer, no, the alternator does not power the clutch because there would be a need for a switch. That switch is inside the car, on the hvac panel and may go thru a relay because a switch can't handle 5-15 amps when relay contacts can. Fused power to the compressor clutch is from the battery.  The fuse and relay are usually in the engine fuse panel.
